# Who were the last moderators directly appointed without an election?

Tags: discussion, moderators, pro-tem-moderators

When the [moderator pro-tempore system](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/07/27/moderator-pro-tempore/) was first implemented, mods would be hand-picked from the community by CMs, often after a nomination thread on Meta - the votes on the nominations would influence the decision but were not the ultimate arbiter of who got a diamond; the CMs would make the final call. (That's how I got my diamond on Literature.SE.)

After a while, more recently, SE switched to running elections for new beta sites - instead of the pseudo-election that the Meta thread of candidates were, an actual election using the election system was run. After a trial run (on Parenting.SE if I recall correctly), this was phased in to all beta sites.

Out of idle curiosity, what was the last set of appointments made directly by the CM team? Who were the last mods appointed in this way rather than through an election? (Also, tangential question: Who is the longest currently-serving appointed mod, rather than elected? I'm not counting runners-up in elections, [which includes Michael Meyers](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/07/11/summer-2010-moderator-appointments/).)

Comment: The recent changes to the moderator listings, to count the oldest addition rather than the newest, have made this harder to tell. As an example, the [page here on this site](/users?tab=moderators) incorrectly states that ChrisF has continuously served as a mod here since 2013, but that's not actually so (that's when they were elected as an SO mod and mods on Trilogy sites were also appointed mods here, then were removed once the MSO-MSE split took place in 2014, then were appointed again in 2018).

Comment: Also, couple of clarification questions: 1. appointed mods also technically includes those who nominated in pro-tem elections and won by default due to there not being more nominees than slots; these mods weren't really elected, but appointed since no one else volunteered. 2. Are you also including moderators on full sites where mods are appointed rather than elected (this site, Ask Patents, and Stack Apps)? If so, the answer might possibly be [Tim Stone on Stack Apps](https://stackapps.com/users?tab=moderators), who (to my knowledge) never ceased to be a mod since their 2013 appointment.

Comment: @SonictheAnti-NewVariant-hog - re: 1: I'm not counting those, since they did run in an actual election. I'm specifically referring to cases where there was no formal election run... 2: ...which would include moderators appointed without an election even if that site is not in beta.

Comment: I may be one of the longest running appointments - see https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators - appointed 21 May 2014

Comment: In practice - I suspect for various reasons stackapps and MSE mods are always gonna be appointed. As this is likely a moving target - as workload and attrition are taken into account, its going to be the newest mod on one of those :D

Answer (score 13):

It's a lot more recent than you might think.

For a variety of reasons, both due to tradition and technical limitations, we still appoint mods manually, without an election, on a couple of sites - specifically, Stack Apps (which doesn't have a meta site and likely couldn't have an election) and Ask Patents, which... is its own sort of special.

Anyway, due to that, the most recent appointments were in June 2021 - Glorfindel and rene were appointed as mods to supplement Tim Stone on [Stack Apps](https://stackapps.com/users?tab=moderators).

Comment: Wasn't Glorfindel being appointed on meta after them being appointed on stack apps? (Or am I having a memory lapse)